# Transaction and Serializability on DBMS - Conflicts

Tags: transactions, conflict, database, serializable

can anyone explain me, why it's so important, that I investigate transaction schedules on conflict for the working with Databases. What means it with conflicts between Transaction, and how will the DBMS treated by them.

I hope that anyone can help me... Thanks :D

Comment: it is not a question but a chapter you asked

Answer (score 1):

A transaction is usefull when you make an insert or an update on a database. 
You don't want that just a part of your data are insert (or update) ! Only two case interest you : nothing or everything.

So, it's like a "try-catch" (in java) ... if everything is ok, you "commit" !! ... else you "rollback" !

Answer (score 0):

A transaction consists of many actions. Consider two actions: an action A1 of T1 and an action A2 of T2. If

1. both A1 and A2 writes to same object V: changing orders of A1 and A2 in a schedule may influence the result, then A1 and A2 are conflict.
2. A1 writes to V and A2 reads V (vice versa): change A1 and A2 will influence the result, then A1 and A2 are conflict.
3. both A1 and A2 reads same object: the order of A1 and A2 are not important, so A1 and A2 are not conflict
4. A1 read/write to V1 and A2 read/write to V2(!= V1): the order of A1 and A2 are not important. Thus A1 A2 not conflict.